# Using Regex to catch dates in many formats

Tags: php, regex, date

I'm working on an app which scrapes local websites to create a database of upcoming events, and I'm trying to use Regex to catch as many formats of dates as possible.

Consider the following sentence fragments:

- "The focus of the seminar, on Saturday 2nd February 2013 will be [...]"
- "Valentines Special @ The Radisson, Feb 14th"
- "On Friday the 15th of February, a special Hollywood themed  [...]"
- "Symposium on Childhood Play on Friday, February 8th"
- "Hosting a craft workshop March 9th - 11th in the old [...]"

I want to be able to scan these and catch as many dates as possible. At the moment I'm doing this in what is probably a flawed way (I'm not great at regex), going through several regex statements one after the other, like this

```
/([0-9]+?)(st|nd|rd|th) (of)? (Jan|Feb|Mar|etc)/i
/([0-9]+?)(st|nd|rd|th) (of)? (January|February|March|Etcetera)/i
/(Jan|Feb|Mar|etc) ([0-9]+?)(st|nd|rd|th)/i
/(January|February|March|Etcetera) ([0-9]+?)(st|nd|rd|th)/i
```

I could merge these all into one giant regex statement, but it seems like there must be a cleaner way of doing this in php, maybe a third-party library or something?

EDIT: The regex above may have errors - it's only meant as an example.

Comment: What is the question exactly? Are you seeking one regular expression equivalent to the four you already have? Is there some reason you can't use multiple?

Comment: These functions may be useful [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php), [date_parse](http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse.php), [strftime](http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php), [strtotime](http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Comment: @erisco, I'm wondering if A) the four+ expressions needed can be neatly merged into one expression or B) if theres a library or function that can do it, like the one suggested below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote a function which extracts dates out of text by using [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime):

```
function parse_date_tokens($tokens) {
  # only try to extract a date if we have 2 or more tokens
  if(!is_array($tokens) || count($tokens) < 2) return false;
  return strtotime(implode(" ", $tokens));
}

function extract_dates($text) {
  static $patterns = Array(
    '/^[0-9]+(st|nd|rd|th|)?$/i', # day
    '/^(Jan(uary)?|Feb(ruary)?|Mar(ch)?|etc)$/i', # month
    '/^20[0-9]{2}$/', # year
    '/^of$/' #words
  );
  # defines which of the above patterns aren't actually part of a date
  static $drop_patterns = Array(
    false,
    false,
    false,
    true
  );
  $tokens = Array();
  $result = Array();
  $text = str_word_count($text, 1, '0123456789'); # get all words in text

  # iterate words and search for matching patterns
  foreach($text as $word) {
    $found = false;
    foreach($patterns as $key => $pattern) {
      if(preg_match($pattern, $word)) {
        if(!$drop_patterns[$key]) {
          $tokens[] = $word;
        }
        $found = true;
        break;
      }
    }

    if(!$found) {
      $result[] = parse_date_tokens($tokens);
      $tokens = Array();
    }
  }
  $result[] = parse_date_tokens($tokens);

  return array_filter($result);
}

# test
$texts = Array(
  "The focus of the seminar, on Saturday 2nd February 2013 will be [...]",
  "Valentines Special @ The Radisson, Feb 14th",
  "On Friday the 15th of February, a special Hollywood themed [...]",
  "Symposium on Childhood Play on Friday, February 8th",
  "Hosting a craft workshop March 9th - 11th in the old [...]"
);

$dates = extract_dates(implode(" ", $texts));
echo "Dates: \n";
foreach($dates as $date) {
  echo "  " . date('d.m.Y H:i:s', $date) . "\n";
}
```

This outputs:

```
Dates: 
  02.02.2013 00:00:00
  14.02.2013 00:00:00
  15.02.2013 00:00:00
  08.02.2013 00:00:00
  09.03.2013 00:00:00
```

This solution may not be perfect and certainly has its flaws but it's a quite simple solution for your problem.

Comment: so did it miss "15th of February" because of the 'of'?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of potentially complex regexes, I tend to break it down into simple pieces that can be individually unit-tested, maintained and evolved.

I use [REL](http://imaginatio.github.com/REL/), a DSL (in Scala) that allows you to reassemble and reuse your regex pieces. This way, you can define your regex [like these Date matchers](https://github.com/Imaginatio/REL/blob/64481efa05ef62b43d4bc31baff3a66b471d07ec/src/main/scala/matchers/Date.scala) and [unit test](https://github.com/Imaginatio/REL/blob/64481efa05ef62b43d4bc31baff3a66b471d07ec/src/test/scala/matchers/DateSpec.scala) on each part.

Also, your unit/spec tests can double as your doc for this bit of regex, indicating what is matched and what is not (which tends to be important with regexes).

In the upcoming version of REL (0.3), you will be directly able to export the Regex in, say, PCRE (thus, PHP) flavor to use it independently… For now only JavaScript and .NET translations are implemented in the github repository. Using the latest (not yet publicly committed) snapshot, the PCRE flavor of the English alphanumeric date regex is this:

```
/(?:(?:(?<!\d)(?<a_d1>(?>(?:(?:[23]?1)st|(?:2?2)nd|(?:2?3)rd|(?:[12]?[4-9]|[123]0)th)\b|0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]|[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))(?: ?+(?:of )?+))(?>(?<a_m1>jan(?>uary|\.)?|feb(?>ruary|r?\.?)?|mar(?>ch|\.)?|apr(?>il|\.)?|may|jun(?>e|\.)?|jul(?>y|\.)?|aug(?>ust|\.)?|sep(?>tember|t?\.?)?|oct(?>ober|\.)?|nov(?>ember|\.)?|dec(?>ember|\.)?))|(?:\b(?>(?<a_m2>jan(?>uary|\.)?|feb(?>ruary|r?\.?)?|mar(?>ch|\.)?|apr(?>il|\.)?|may|jun(?>e|\.)?|jul(?>y|\.)?|aug(?>ust|\.)?|sep(?>tember|t?\.?)?|oct(?>ober|\.)?|nov(?>ember|\.)?|dec(?>ember|\.)?)))(?:(?:(?: ?+)(?<a_d2>(?>(?:(?:[23]?1)st|(?:2?2)nd|(?:2?3)rd|(?:[12]?[4-9]|[123]0)th)\b|0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]|[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))(?!\d))?))(?:(?:,?+)(?:(?:(?: ?)(?<a_y>(?:1[7-9]|20)\d\d|'?+\d\d))(?!\d))|(?<=\b|\.))/i
```

Obtained via expressing `fr.splayce.rel.matchers.en.Date.ALPHA` using `PCREFlavor` (not yet in the GitHub repository). It will only match when there is a month, expressed in alphabetic form (`feb`, `feb.` or `february`), the `….Date.ALL` regex also matching numerical forms like `2/21/2013` is more complex.

Also, this particular regex matches your examples but may still be a bit limited for your needs:

- It does not include the week days
- It will not match date ranges (matched only `March 9th`)
- It will not match with year first e.g. `2013, jan. 14th`